# Preventing parent window redirection from child

Tags: javascript, redirect, parent, window.opener

I have a website where I HAVE to link to another website, this other website contains this code:

```
if (parent.window.opener) parent.window.opener.location='http://AdvertisingURL';
if (self.parent.frames.length!=0) self.parent.location=document.location;
```

The link on my site is a normal link with target=_blank, when I click on it, the site containing that code opens in a new windows, and then my website gets redirected to the advertising URL.

**How could I block that redirection without any alert message?**